# add columns to a list via powershell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to do the following but I have some exceptions, I dont know whats wrong with this.

**Update 2:**

```
    $site = Get-SPSite -Identity "http://url/workspaces/TS1/"
$list = $site.RootWeb.GetList("/workspaces/TS1/Lists/WorkspaceAccessRights")
```

I tried this simple 1. and it says

```
Exception calling "GetList" with "1" argument(s): "Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))"
At line:15 char:30
+ $list = $site.RootWeb.GetList <<<< ("/workspaces/TS1/Lists/WorkspaceAccessRights/")
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved with this blog:
http://www.stilldesign.co.nz/Blog/post/2011/06/21/Painful-SharePoint-error-when-using-PowerShell.aspx#comment

Perhaps I should have mentioned that I am using POWERGUI, after checking the logs at the exact same time of the script execution, I could copy and paste the error and find the blog above.

I blogged about this here: 
http://levalencia.wordpress.com/2012/04/12/unable-to-cast-com-object-of-type-microsoft-sharepoint-library-sprequestinternalclass-to-interface-type-microsoft-sharepoint-library-isprequest/

Comment: Don't forget to select this as the answer. Also, it would be a good idea to give a short explanation of what was going on in case the post is deleted or the site goes away.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than using

```
$spList = $spWeb.GetList("/Lists/Mylist")
```

try

```
$spList = $spWeb.Lists["My list"]
```

or

```
$spList = $spWeb.GetList("/sitename/Lists/Mylist")
```

It seems like all the errors are related to the fact that $spList is null.

Comment: pls see my update, last line is throwing Cannot convert value to type System.String.
At line:31 char:18
+ Write-Host "$spWe <<<< b"
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RuntimeException

Comment: Is this a typo? $spList = $web.Lists["Workspace Access Rights"]   where you have $web instead of $spWeb?

Comment: psl see the edit, now access denied?, this is weird